# Converting underscore URL's PHP query to dash/hyphened URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

Trying to find the answer to my problem, I have looked at other posts but can't find the exact issue. I have dyanamic URL's which GET product data. I'm happy to make new pages to create SEO friendly URL's but i'd rather do something with HTACCESS if possible.

I currently have:

https://example.com/product?product_id=business-cards

I want to get the URL without the underscore so:

https://example.com/product?product-id=business-cards

This is my current basic HTACCESS, only thing I am doing currently is removing the .php at the end:

```
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# This domain inherits the “PHP” package.
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit

IndexIgnore * # prevent directory listing

Order deny,allow
Allow from *

# ------------------------------------------
# Rewrite so that php extentions are not shown
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php


ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: ___Small Point___ _SEO friendly URL's_ are done in the `.htaccess` file as well

Comment: If you do this in htaccess, your PHP will still be generating the links with underscores. In your htaccess, if you don't redirect, then you aren't solving a problem really. If you do redirect, then your PHP will be generating non-canonical links which is sub-optimal for SEO. Just do this in PHP.

Comment: Problem is thats not a variable i can control since its from the API so I can only get product_ID

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to change a single query   perameter in your URLs from `product_id` to `product-id`  then the following should work

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^product_id=(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^product/?$ /product/?product-id=%1 [L,R,NE]
```